# GoogleCharts API -- Showing multiple tooltips

Tags: python, google-visualization

I have the following chart, which contains three lines:

[image]

I have three lines here, and I would like to see the data of all three lines at the same time when I hove over a specific time. Is this possible in Google Charts. If so, how would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding to the chart options:

```
aggregationTarget: 'category'
```

As documentation says about `aggregationTarget` :

> How multiple data selections are rolled up into tooltips:
>   'category': Group selected data by x-value.
>   'series': Group selected data by series.
>   'auto': Group selected data by x-value if all selections have the same x-value, and by series otherwise.
>   'none': Show only one tooltip per selection.

You can view full details here : [Google Line Chart Configuration](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#Configuration_Options)

Comment: how to use this option as i can not see the result, https://jsfiddle.net/14bfygcc/1/

Comment: @PurveshDesai does not seem to be working anymore, might need to contact google chart support or build your own tooltip with both data points and use custom tooltip

Answer (score 0):

`aggregationTarget: 'category'` is not working anymore, so instead of that we need to use `focusTarget: 'category'` for to get the all data points with the same tooltip.